# average number of words in a character vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe, character, word-count

i'm trying to get the average number of words in my character vector in R

```
one <- c(9, 23, 43)
two <- c("this is a new york times article.", "short article.", "he went outside to smoke a cigarette.")

mydf <- data.frame(one, two)
mydf

#   one                                   two
# 1   9     this is a new york times article.
# 2  23                        short article.
# 3  43 he went outside to smoke a cigarette.
```

i'm looking for a function that gives me the average number of words of character vector "two".

the output here should be 5.3333  (=(7+2+7)/3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or `gregexpr()`

```
mean(sapply(mydf$two,function(x)length(unlist(gregexpr(" ",x)))+1))
[1] 5.333333
```

Comment: `mean(sapply(gregexpr(" ", mydf$two), length)+1)` is the same concept but a little more concise....

Comment: @AnandaMahto yes good point, not sure why I didn't do that first

Comment: My *guess* is that you would get a speed boost if you used my suggestion, because it reduces the number of calls to `gregexpr`. I would also suggest that the actual solution would involve (1) first trimming any leading and trailing spaces that might be there and (2) making your search term something like `"\\s+"`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possibility with the qdap package:

```
library(qdap)
wc(mydf$two, FALSE)/nrow(mydf)

## [1] 5.333333
```

This is overkill but you could also do:

```
word_stats(mydf$two)

##   all n.sent n.words n.char n.syl n.poly   wps    cps   sps psps   cpw   spw pspw n.state proDF2 n.hapax n.dis grow.rate prop.dis
## 1 all      3      16     68    23      3 5.333 22.667 7.667    1 4.250 1.438 .188       3      1      12     2      .750     .125
```

And `wps` column is words per sentence.

Comment: Once you create the word_stats object and assign it to an object with that class, why does plot.word_stats(obj) not work?

Comment: Generic `plot` objects work off of classes so if you've altered the class or the new class has its own plot method then the generic `plot` will not work any more.  In any event `plot` for `word_stats` is just a wrapper for `qheat` so you could still use `qheat` on it.

Comment: @lawyeR If this doesn't answer the question open a new question with data and an example.

Answer (score 2):

Hadley Wickham's stringr package provides possibly the easiest way for this:

```
library(stringr)
foo<- str_split(two, " ") # split each element of your vector by the space sign
sapply(foo,length) # just a quick test: how many words has each element?
sum(sapply(foo,length))/length(foo) # calculate sum and divide it by the length of your original object
[1] 5.333333
```

Comment: The stringr way looks very similar to the base way. The only difference seems to be the underscore. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are some more elaborated methods available but you can use `strsplit` to split your strings at spaces into a character vector and count its length of elements.

```
mean(sapply(strsplit(as.character(mydf$two), "[[:space:]]+"), length))
# [1] 5.3333
```